# Why Would Different Pointers Act As If They Shared The Same Values?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Below I used two different functions to initialize a 2D array. Each returns an array, which is stored in an appropriate pointer. There are no global variables. When one is given a value, they both act as if they have received it. Code and log illustrate.

Try as I might, I can't see why this makes sense. At first, both uninitialized values makes sense. But after that why does setting A also set B the same? Why does then setting B overwrite A?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int **MakePtrArrayA( int Size ){
    int ** myArr = new int*[ Size ];
    for( int x=0; x<Size; x++ ){
        myArr[x] = new int;
    }
    return myArr;
}

int **MakePtrArrayB( int Size){
    int ** myArr;
    for( int x=0; x<Size; x++ ){
        myArr[x] = new int[ Size ];
    }
    return myArr;
}

int main(){
    int ** arrA = MakePtrArrayA( 5 );
    int ** arrB = MakePtrArrayB( 5 );
    std::cout << "A:" << arrA[4][4] << std::endl << "B:" << arrB[4][4] << std::endl;
    arrA[4][4] = 16;
    std::cout << "A:" << arrA[4][4] << std::endl << "B:" << arrB[4][4] << std::endl;
    arrB[4][4] = 15;
    std::cout << "A:" << arrA[4][4] << std::endl << "B:" << arrB[4][4] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Log:

```
A:0
B:0
A:16
B:16
A:15
B:15
```

Comment: You have undefined behavior creating both arrays.

Comment: Or at least if MakePtrArrayA is correct you can not use arrA[4][4] since the second dimension is of size 1.

Comment: warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'myArr' used for this line `myArr[x] = new int[ Size ];`

Comment: Using `std::vector<std::vector>` would avoid at least one of these issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MakePtrArrayB` invokes undefined behavior, by using an uninitialized pointer.

Undefined behavior can be *anything*, but in your case, the `myArr` pointer in `MakePtrArrayB` probably occupies the same memory as the one in `MakePtrArrayA`, so the loop accesses the original array (setting it to newly allocated row buffers that are big enough for the subsequent accesses).

But you cannot rely on this behavior.  Fix the bugs.

Comment: Specifically, the two functions have the same stack layout (same parameter types and local variables) and so the call to `MakePtrArrayB` gets the same bit of stack for its frame that `MakePtrArrayA` had, meaning that `myArr` gets the same value it had in the first function call.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, and called in the same context, and the compiler decided not to optimize away access to a variable causing undefined behavior (which is perfectly legal for it to do).

Answer (score 3):

You are not initializing the value of `myArr` in `MakePtrArrayB`. As such, the result of dereferencing that pointer is **undefined** — anything could potentially happen.

In this case, what's happening is that the value of `myArr` is reusing the same value that was set during the previous call of `MakePtrArrayA`. (This is most likely happening because the two functions have the same stack layout, and the stack location has not been overwritten by anything else.) Obviously, you should not depend on this behavior! It won't work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem not mentioned by previous answers is that you access out of bounds on `arrA`:

```
int **MakePtrArrayA( int Size ){
    int ** myArr = new int*[ Size ];
    for( int x=0; x<Size; x++ ){
        myArr[x] = new int;             // <--- row length 1
```

In main:

```
std::cout << "A:" << arrA[4][4]         // <--- access 5th element
```